# What is the time complexity of collections.Counter() in Python?

Tags: python, time-complexity

```
collection.Counter("bcdefffaa")
```

returns output:

```
Counter({'f': 3, 'a': 2, 'c': 1, 'b': 1, 'e': 1, 'd': 1})
```

Since the result is in descended sorted order of values, does this mean the cost of building the Counter is `O(nlogn)` and not `O(n)`?

Comment: It does **not** sort the string first. This is simply dictionary lookup. So the worst time complexity is *O(n^2)*, but this is *very* rare. Usually it is *O(n)*.

Comment: For Java see: http://stackoverflow.com/documentation/java/88/streams/909/creating-a-frequency-map

Answer (score 44, accepted):

As the [source code](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/0250de48199552cdaed5a4fe44b3f9cdb5325363/Lib/collections/__init__.py#L497) shows, Counter is just a subclass of dict. Constructing it is O(n), because it has to iterate over the input, but operations on individual elements remain O(1).

Note also from that source that it does not keep an order internally, but simply sorts by most common on output, in the `__repr__` method.

Comment: But if look to [repr](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/0250de48199552cdaed5a4fe44b3f9cdb5325363/Lib/collections/__init__.py#L707) we could see that it use [most_common](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/0250de48199552cdaed5a4fe44b3f9cdb5325363/Lib/collections/__init__.py#L573) and their complexity O(nlog(n))

Comment: Agree with cruim. The most_common would be using the default Python's sort implementation (Timsort), which is O(n log n)

Comment: What is the time complexity for `Counter(YOUR_DICT.values())[WANTED_NUMBER]` ?

Answer (score 3):

Depends on the implementation, obviously, but the factors that matter are the need to touch each element of the original list, which implies O(n) is a lower bound, and the need to insert elements into a dict and/or update a dict. 
The display of the elements in the output is not relevant to the cost of building the Counter.