# Python data structures - sorting big O complexity implementation

Tags: python, sorting, big-o

We all have been told the popular theoretical limit for a general case sorting of objects to be O(n*log(n)) in many languages.

Let's say we have a list:

```
lst = [1,1,2,3,4,5,3,2,3,4,2,1,2,3]
```

In Python, I was recently introduced to some additional benefits of using Counter (`from collections import Counter`) over dictionary with keys as list numbers and values as their occurrence counter.

```
coun = Counter(lst) 
print(coun) # ==> Counter({2: 4, 3: 4, 1: 3, 4: 2, 5: 1})
```

It was shown several times ([What is the time complexity of collections.Counter() in Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42461840/what-is-the-time-complexity-of-collections-counter-in-python/42461996)) that construction of Counter takes O(n) and unlike standard dict, Counter() has **some additional space overhead** to store frequencies of each element.

When you attempt to work with Counter, it often returns outputs in the sorted order:
`.items()` or `.keys()`. Maybe for sake of convenience it applies a quick O(logn) sorting before giving you the result, but it sounds unexpectedly bad, when you will use it in simple traversing:

```
for i in range(len(lst)):
    if lst[i] not in coun.keys():
        print("element", lst[i], "not found!")
```

You would naturally expect that complexity of above will be O(n) as in a standard dictionary (check presence is O(1) over n loops).

So without picking in the code, *let's just assume* that `lst[i] not in coun.keys()` is implemented in a O(1) complexity, using some space overhead.

Is it **theoretically possible** that during counter construction, this additional (potentially prohibitively large for really big and unique lists) space overhead is giving us an edge in small and medium sized lists (length < 1000) to get the O(n) sorting advantage at a cost of using extra space.
If above is possible, I assume that behind the scenes there is a mechanism that will stop counting every single element and putting them into the correct sorted order, when memory footprint is breaking some defined value (like 1Mb) and `lst[i] not in coun.keys()` becomes O(logn).

Just thinking outloud here, as in reality a lot of lists that we are working with actually are less than 1000 elements.

**Afterthought 1:**
On the other hand, you probably wouldn't care much for O(n) vs O(nlogn) when n<1000 it will be barely noticable time gain at a potentially huge space overhead price.

**Afterthought 2:**
It appears that .keys() is preserving the insertion order, that just happened to be the same as sorted order due to my poor initial data set.

Nevertheless, is it possible to have implementation of data structure that will place the counted objects in the right places at the moment of adding them?

Comment: "and unlike standard dict, Counter() has some additional space overhead to store frequencies of each element." No, no it doesn't.

Comment: Also, `Counter` does not maintain sorted keys. Your question rests on untrue assumptions. Which Python version are you using? In recent versions dicts maintain insertion order

Comment: `from collections import Counter
myList = [1,1,2,3,4,5,3,2,3,4,2,1,2,3]
print(Counter(myList))
#Counter({2: 4, 3: 4, 1: 3, 4: 2, 5: 1})
print(Counter(myList).items())
dict_items([(1, 3), (2, 4), (3, 4), (4, 2), (5, 1)])
print(Counter(myList).keys())
dict_keys([1, 2, 3, 4, 5])`



You are right, I just have a bad initial data example. If I change order in the original data, keys() doesn't return anymore the sorted list.

Comment: So, presumbably you are using Python >3.6? Dict keys maintain insertion order

Comment: yes, sounds like it was my overlook on the example that gave me feeling as if they are sorted.

Comment: A `set` [might sort](https://tio.run/##K6gsycjPM7YoKPr/P60oP1ehKDEvBUhl5hbkF5UoFGeUpqXlpHJx5RSXKNgqRBvqGOoY6RjrmOiYAkkIywgiFsuVll@kEK@QmQcyIz1Vw9BA04pLAQighmgAzdAECxQUZeaVaGgVp5aAxTT//wcA) like you thought `Counter` did, so you could use a `set` to determine the order of the unique values and a `Counter` to get their multiplicities.

Comment: @superbrain but why would you do that? Why not just use `sorted`? That would *guarantee* that you would get the sorted order, and not just rely on implementation details and luck of the draw.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The O(n*log(n)) lower bound on sorting algorithms only applies to algorithms that can sort arbitrary objects by comparing them to one another. If you know that your data is from a limited domain, you can use more efficient algorithms. For example, if the values are all small integers you can use a [counting sort](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Counting_sort) to efficiently sort the data in O(n) time.

Here's an example that can sort sequences that only contain integers from the domain 0-5, like in your example.

```
def sort_0_to_5(data):
    counts = [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]
    for val in data:
        counts[val] += 1
    return [val for val in range(len(counts)) for _ in range(counts[val])]
```

This runs in O(n) time and uses only constant space. This is a very basic counting sort, a fancier version could sort arbitrary objects as long as they have integer keys within the domain. (You just need a couple extra passes over the data to make cumulative counts and then to build up the output in the right order.)

More sophisticated algorithms like radix sort can handle much larger domains in quasi-linear time. The way you need to account for time gets tricky though, as once the domain starts getting comparable to the size of the data set, the less "constant" the parts of the code that deal with the domain size become. Radix sort, for example, takes O(n*log(k)) time where k is the size of the domain.

I'd note however that even if you can figure out a sorting algorithm that has a better time complexity than the standard comparison sorts, that may not actually mean it is faster for your actual data. Unless the size of your data set is huge, the constant terms that get excluded from asymptotic analysis are likely to matter quite a lot. You may find that a very well implemented O(n*log(n)) sort (like the one behind Python's `sorted`) performs better than a O(n) sort you've coded up by hand.

Comment: Very good thoughts for consideration. Thank you!