# Time Complexity to create a dictionary from a list in python

Tags: python, dictionary, hashmap, time-complexity

What would be the time complexity to create a dictionary for frequency of occurrence of elements in a list (in python)?

For example: I have a list - ls = [5,3,3,2]
I want to create a dictionary to check frequency of each element in the list. This is the code for that:

```
freq = {}
for ele in ls:
    if ele in freq:
        freq[ele] += 1
    else:
        freq[ele] = 1
```

This will create the dictionary from the list, but what would the time complexity be to create the dictionary?

Any insights on this would be helpful. Thank you.

Comment: It's `O(n)`. Take a look at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42461840/what-is-the-time-complexity-of-collections-counter-in-python

Answer (score 4):

It would be linear `O(n)` complexity as you are only iterating through the list once with no nested loops/recursion/etc... As for checking `ele in freq` it is `O(1)` complexity as dicts are hash maps and using `dict.__contains__` only does a hash lookup for the value. Although using `collections.Counter` is the more preferred way:

```
from collections import Counter

ls = [5,3,3,2]
freq = Counter(ls)
```

---

```
>>> dict(freq)
{5: 1, 3: 2, 2: 1}
```

Comment: Thank you for the clarification. But for every element in the list, we would have to traverse through the entire dictionary to find if the element is already present in it or has to be added. So in that case, would the complexity be much larger (worst case - O(n^2))?

Comment: @Aadi Nope, searching for a key in dict is `O(1)` i.e. constant time. Dicts are implemented using hashmaps.

Comment: Dictionary keys are a hash table, thus checking possession is O(1) complexity. I'ts a hash lookup not an iterative lookup.

Comment: I edited my answer to include this explination.

Comment: @Jab Unless you're under attack and it does degrade to linear time lookup. With ints that's even easy.

Comment: @nocomment I'm not sure I follow what you're saying.

Comment: @Jab I mean if you do it as part of a system and I as an attacker can feed you numbers I choose, I can easily make your lookups linear and the whole thing quadratic and make your system slow that way.

Comment: Didn't even think about that.

Comment: @Jab [Demo](https://tio.run/##fY5BCsIwEEX3OcUsk6LQKIgIXfUY4iKtqQ4kM2FMF54@VmsXiji7z3@fN@mer0zbfZJSBuEIGaPHDBgTS34n9Wp6DsH3GZluS93ySNmLUgQN2Ho6RSzRhSkeESrQm6ra2XVtYGABBCQQRxevyZxU9I4AvlD7E1VJkLKe39HBxe7sDotez06zAhpj56WxxvwfPM0feCkP) with a "normal" and a "mean" list of  numbers.

Answer (score 1):

It should be linear `O(n)` because you are just looping from first to last of the list linearly.