# Time complexity of count inside the loop

Tags: python, algorithm, time-complexity, big-o

Which time complexety this code have?

```py
line = "..."
occuriences_cnt = {char: line.count(char) for char in line}
```

I'm assuming that this is `0(n^2)`, because there is `count` - O(n) in loop. Am I wrong?

Comment: yes, and you can use `collections.Counter` to reduce it to `O(n)`, see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42461840/what-is-the-time-complexity-of-collections-counter-in-python

Comment: Documentation https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#textseq does not say anything about complexity of `.count` so you have to make an educated guess - it is unlikely there is any caching so `count` have to do linear search - O(string_length).   I'd recommend writing it out yourself if you need that to explain complexity.

Comment: This might be helpful https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44812468/what-is-the-time-complexity-of-python-lists-count-function